# SQL find timestamp where sum of visitors was greatest

Tags: sql, postgresql

I spent a lot of time solving this problem. So, I have table `users`:

| at_timestamp | users_count | event_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100000 | 2 | 1 |
| 100001 | 4 | 1 |
| 100003 | 5 | 0 |
| 100005 | 1 | 1 |
| 100006 | 3 | 1 |
| 100008 | 2 | 0 |
| 100008 | 1 | 1 |

etc.

So, event type 1 means IN, and 0 means OUT. I need to find timestamp, when the sum of users was the higest. In this example it was 100001, because 2 + 4 = 6. Then 5 are out and 1 left. Then 1 user in, 3 users are in, which means total users count at the 100006 ts was 5. Then in the same time, 2 leave and 1 in  and so on. I am have tried to use window functions, but without IF/ELSE, or something, but it doesn't work for me. I got something close to, but not exactly what i need.

Example of my postgres query

```
SELECT at_timestamp, sum(users_count) OVER (PARTITION BY event_type ORDER BY at_timestamp)
FROM users_events;
```

Then I have tried

```
SELECT at_timestamp, sum(users_count) OVER (partition by event_type ORDER BY at_timestamp) - LAG(users_count) OVER (PARTITION BY event_type) FROM users_events;
```

But it doesn't work, because i need to subtract previous value, if it is out event. So, i need SQL query which will calculate it right 
I will be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this arithmetically with your initial approach, if you get rid of the `partition by`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LhROmdIx)

```sql
SELECT at_timestamp, 
       sum(users_count*(2*event_type-1)) OVER (ORDER BY at_timestamp)
FROM users_events
ORDER BY at_timestamp;
```

That's because

- `event_type` seems to be an `integer`
- `2 * 0 - 1` is `-1` and
- `2 * 1 - 1` is `1`

Using this as a multiplier, `event_type` of `0` causes subtraction of corresponding `users_count` from the stepping sum, and `event_type` of `1` results in addition of the `users_count`

Comment: Thank you a lot! That math looks very tricky but it's better than using CASE WHEN, and it works perfectly! Thank you for help and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

```
with tallied as (
    select *,
        sum(user_count
              * case when event_type = 1
                     then 1 else -1 end) over (
            order by at_timestamp) as tally
    from T
), ranked as (
    select *,
        dense_rank() over (
            order by tally desc) as dr
    from tallied
) 
select * from ranked where dr = 1;
```

Because of the potential for ties in the ranking, this uses `dense_rank()` to filter for maximal output rows.

Answer (score 1):

Short and concise: a CASE WHEN multiplier as from @shawnt00 in a running sum expression using a window clause. I use a *named window* because I find it more readable and PostgreSQL allows it.

And finally order by the running sum descending and applying a LIMIT 1:

```
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ psql -af rsum.sql
WITH
-- Your in data ...
indata(at_timestamp,users_count,event_type) AS (
          SELECT 100000,2,1
UNION ALL SELECT 100001,4,1
UNION ALL SELECT 100003,5,0
UNION ALL SELECT 100005,1,1
UNION ALL SELECT 100006,3,1
UNION ALL SELECT 100008,2,0
UNION ALL SELECT 100008,1,1
)
-- real query starts here ...
SELECT 
  *
, SUM(users_count * CASE event_type WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) OVER w AS runsum
FROM indata
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY at_timestamp)
ORDER BY 4 DESC LIMIT 1;
 at_timestamp | users_count | event_type | runsum 
--------------+-------------+------------+--------
       100001 |           4 |          1 |      6
```